# Modal forms and Django URLs, how to work?

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

html

```
<form action="{% url 'sp_feedback' %}" method="post">
```

url

```
url(r'^feedback/$', views.post_feedback, name="sp_feedback"),
```

views:

```
 return HttpResponseRedirect("")
```

In using modal forms, how do you, after hitting submit, return to the page?

In my current setup, the browser redirects to nothing. I'm completely confused on what to put in the url regular expressions.

Comment: try this return HttpResponseRedirect('/feedback/')

Answer (score 1):

> In my current setup, the browser redirects to nothing.

Because you're redirecting to an empty URL:

```
return HttpResponseRedirect("")
```

You've to redirect to the url of the page:

```
return HttpResponseRedirect('/feedback/')
```

---

But it is rather better and convenient to use the [`redirect()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect) shortcut. Because you can pass it the name of the url and Django will automatically make the redirect to the associated url.

Example:

```
return redirect('sp_feedback')
```

It is a good practice to avoid using hardcoded urls in your application.

---

**UPDATE**

Since you mention that this form is on every page and you'd like to redirect the user back to that page, here's one solution:

Use [`request.META['HTTP_REFERER']`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.META) in your form view to get the referring page, then use that value to make the redirect:

```
redirect_to = request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER', '/') # if HTTP-Referer header is not present, just redirect to homepage
return HttpResponseRedirect(redirect_to)
```

Comment: Yes, but what should I put in the URL? Since I'm using a modal form, it's featured in every page. Is there a way to redirect it to the same page?